# Synergy input doesn't work in a VM with VMware Workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am using VMware Workstation version 10.0.3 build 18955310, this is used for personal development.  When using synergy both mouse and keyboard inputs are not available within the virtual machine.  Is there a fix to this issue.

Answer (score -1):

With the VM running, terminate all synergy related processes on the server.

Then restart the synergy service by typing `services.msc` in the Start menu -> press ENTER -> navigate to Synergy -> right click, Restart.

Open Synergy on server and reconnect to the client. Your VM should now have keyboard and mouse input.

This worked on VMWare workstation 9, Synergy 1.4.16, Windows 7.